# Spring junit test Error "could not find current request via RequestContextHolder"

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I use spring framework 4 and have class that has his line :

```
 String link = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/admin/menu/edit/"+id).build().toUriString();
```

Class perfectly run in on server but when I want to unit test it and create the class and call method that use above could got a error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.getCurrentRequest(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:158)
at com.mohsenj.core.util.HiararchyUtils.createTableTrMenu(HiararchyUtils.java:175)
at com.mohsenj.core.util.HiararchyUtils.getHForTableMenu(HiararchyUtils.java:153)
at com.mohsenj.core.util.HiararchyUtils.getHForTableMenu(HiararchyUtils.java:158)
at com.mohsenj.core.util.HiararchyUtilsTest.getHForTableMenu_verifyReturnString(HiararchyUtilsTest.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

my class:

```
@Component
public class HiararchyUtils {
    public String getHForTableMenu(List<? extends Hierarchically> menus,      Integer parentId) {

    seperateParentsIntoAssoc(menus);
    return createTableTrMenu(parentId, 0);
    }

    public String createTableTrMenu(Integer parent, Integer level) {

          // some code
            String link = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/admin/menu/edit/"+items.get(itemId).getId()).build().toUriString();

          // some code
     }}
```

test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
     public class HiararchyUtilsTest {

      private HiararchyUtils hiararchyUtils;


@Before
public void setup() {

    hiararchyUtils = new HiararchyUtils();

}

@Test
public void getHForTableMenu_() {

    String trs = hiararchyUtils.getHForTableMenu(menus);
}
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: How is your test setup? only one line or prod code is too few to answer

Comment: @arne-burmeister I update question

Comment: This link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819299/how-to-write-a-mockito-test-case-for-resourceassembler-with-in-spring-hateos/43586532#43586532

Answer (score 3):

It may be as easy as adding a `MockHttpServletRequest` in order to provide the needed `RequestContextHolder` and context path.

As a class variable, add

```
private MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest;
```

Then, when setting up your test(s), try:

```
@Before
mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
mockRequest.setContextPath("/your-app-context");

ServletRequestAttributes attrs = new ServletRequestAttributes(mockRequest);

RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attrs);
```

That should address that error.